# Contexto de persistencia Eclipselink 2.6.4 - rollback - Java 8 SE

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Al generar rollback de una transacción para actualizar una entidad, esta no queda manejada en el contexto de persistencia. El problema es que luego, haciendo un `merge` de esta entidad con el mismo entityManager que utilizo para persistir, tampoco se agrega al contexto de persistencia.

Código que se llama mas de una vez, sin cerrar ni iniciar un nuevo EntityManager:

```
public void actualizar (Entidad e, EntityManager em) throws Exception {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    
    if (!em.contains(e)) { //si la entidad no esta manejada
        em.merge(e);
    }
    
    em.refresh(e);
    
    em.persist(e);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

En la primer llamada este método retorna PersistenceException (porque le seteo mal un dato para que la genere). Al volver a llamarlo, la entidad `e` no está manejada por el contexto de persistencia, y al hacer el `merge` tampoco la agrega. Entonces el `refresh` que sigue en el método lanza la excepción
*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot refresh unmanaged object*.

Por otro lado, después de la primer llamada, si en el método que invoca a este hago

```
em.find(e); //obtiene la entidad de la cache JPA
em.refresh(e);
```

antes de llamar a `actualizar(e, em)`, el `refresh` lanza la misma excepción de arriba.

Hay alguna forma de volver manejar la entidad? O tal vez no es correcto el enfoque que le estoy dando al problema.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución encontrada: al hacer el `merge` se tiene que hacer

`e = em.merge(e);`

De esta maneta se obtiene la entidad manejada.